# achieve replaceAll functionality in java 1.2

Tags: java

I have below code

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){
  String Str = new String("Welcome to java world !");

  System.out.print("Return Value :" );
  System.out.println(Str.replaceAll(" ",
                     "%20" ));
}
}
```

This produces the following result:

```
Return Value :Welcome%20to%20java%20world%20!
```

But the issue is that i am using legacy java 1.2 in our project there is no support for replaceAll in String class or replace in StringBuffer class. How to achieve replaceAll logic in java 1.2 to replace all space with %20

Comment: iterate over `String` and use `charAt()` method to replace " " to `%20`

Comment: You *really* shouldn't be using Java 1.2 for anything nowadays, considering that it's not supported, full of security holes, isn't as performant as modern versions, and doesn't have a lot of the "core" functionality that modern Java has.  But hey, this is my opinion - I can only salute you if you simply can't move away from it.  But if you can, please, do.

Answer (score 5):

I'm ***very*** serious when I say you should migrate away from 1.2, but even though you're messing with an archaic version, it isn't like you don't have some primitive tools.

[`StringTokenizer`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs368-2/JavaTutorial/jdk1.2/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) is available to use, and considering that it can tokenize strings with spaces in it by default, this should give you a leg up on how to solve this problem.

The steps are simple:

- Create a `StringTokenizer` instance
- Consume the string via the tokenizer and place it into the `StringBuffer`
- Immediately after the string is consumed, place `"%20"` after it
- Do not add the previous string if there are no more tokens to add

As a *rough*, untested* approach, this is something I'd go for:

```
public String replace(String phrase, String token, String replacement) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(phrase, token);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        stringBuffer.append(st.nextToken());
        stringBuffer.append(replacement);
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

<sup>*:  untestable; I <s>can't</s> won't download a copy of Java 1.2.</sup>

Comment: at some point, you might want to add the replacement to the stringbuffer

Comment: I've fixed the lack of use of `replacement`, as well as renamed the method.